# different result multiple query with rand boolean mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

I need to give a result that differs:

1. You can eat sandwich.
2. You can eat sandwich but cannot eat donuts.
3. You can eat donuts and drink.

The whole thing must be pick at random.

The problem is the result.

First I had to make a mysql database boolean table that consist of

```
 +-------------------------------------+
 |  ids|name | sandwich | donuts| drink|
 |   1 | josh|    1     |   1   |   1  |
 |   2 | john|    0     |   1   |   0  |
 |   3 | mike|    1     |   0   |   0  |
 |   4 | mic |    0     |   1   |   1  |
 +=====================================+
```

I had written some code in php but it seem that the first goal is ok but the second one I had a problem. The problem is that the second one. Someone cannot eat sandwich at the same time eat donut..
The result that i get from the second one is that it shows the list of people that eat donut and not what i want.

Is there any problem with the code?..

Here is the php code that i had done..

```
    <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="test1"; // Database name
$tbl_name="skill"; // Table name


// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT ids, name FROM skill WHERE sandwich='1' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
eat sandwich is
<?
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $rows['name']."<br>";}?>


<br>
eat donut
<?
$sql1="SELECT ids, name FROM skill WHERE donuts='1' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
?>
<?

while($rows1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    if ($result <> $result1)
    {echo $rows1['name'];}
    else
    {echo nono;}
}?>
```

Comment: the purpose of homework is for **you** to do it.

Comment: @Dagon if he want's to get a manager once a day it's ok and preferred to let others do

Comment: What is `nono`? Is there a typo or is it a constant?

Comment: @Dagon please help me if you know the answer..

Comment: Im not sure what is the problem..
Is it the while loop or the query it self?

Comment: Code aside, you really need to work on better explaining a) what you want it to do, and b) what it's currently doing that's incorrect.

Comment: @tadman a)the first while loop code should display randomly the name of the person that eat the sandwich..second while loop code should display randomly name of person that eat donut without eat sandwich.. b) the problem is the second while loop..why it didn't compare the answer with the first while loop?..because the result that i get is it give me all the person that eat donut including the person that eat sandwich.. please help me

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ nono is just a constant i mean it should be the error message

Comment: you need different thinking. you just need to put your data into groups. field like id,name,food,drink. food is either ['sandwich','donut'], drink is either ['water','lime juice'] then you will not need loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing with that `while` loop. Express the restrictions as a `WHERE` clause even if it's very verbose, like:

```
SELECT ... FROM users
  WHERE (sandwich='1' AND donuts!='1')
    OR (sandwich='0')
  ORDER BY RAND()
```

Any other restrictions on what rows to select can be layered in there.

As a note, unless you absolutely must, do not use `mysql_query` in new code. It's being removed from PHP because it's terribly out of date and unsafe when used incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.. Thank you.. It seem there are lot for me to learn.. Thanks for your guide.. I really appreciate the help.. Actually I use the while loop to represent the various random of name if the limit for rand is more than 1.. Thanks again sir.. Will post question again if help is needed..